# If statement shorthand syntax in MYSQL store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN

    INSERT IGNORE INTO users ( group_id, username, password, email) 
    SELECT status, CONCAT(first_name, last_name), password, email FROM another_user;

END
```

Here is a sample I wanna write status from another_user into group_id in users directly.

Is there any method to do like Java if else shorthand syntax? If can the statement would be like this:

```
SELECT (status==1?4,5), CONCAT(first_name, last_name), password, email FROM another_user;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the `IF` function:

```
SELECT IF(status = 1, 4, 5), CONCAT(first_name, last_name), password, email
FROM another_user;
```

You can also use the standard SQL `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE status
        WHEN 1 THEN 4
        ELSE 5
       END,
        CONCAT(first_name, last_name), password, email
FROM another_user;
```

This is not particular to stored procedures, it's just a general feature of SQL expressions, and you can use it anywhere.